# Python Telebot - Forwarding is not working for media

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

So, I have to forward incoming channel post to my **private chat** for test purpose. Now, it works, but **only with texts**. If the channel post is a **media**, it **doesn't** forward the message.

That's the code that forward posts:

```
bot.forward_message(myId, '@ ' + username, msg.message_id)
# Where: myId is my telegram chat ID; '@' + username is the channel (done like this because 
# there will be multiple channels); msg.message_id is the ID of the message  it has to forward
```

I'm using the library pyTelegramBotAPI (module's name is **telebot**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out how to make it works. With pyTelegramBotAPI, just put the content_types parameters in the decorator:

```
@bot.channel_post_handler(content_types = ['text', 'photo', 'video', 'gif', 'sticker'])
def channel_post_handler(msg):
    # Your code here
```

The same could be done in `@bot.message_handler`, as you can pass it the same parameter of `@bot.channel_post_handler`